# Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder' in your configuration

Tags: java

I have moved from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 and Java 8 to Java 11. More I have upgraded my springframework to version 2. For the same code I get the following error:

Description:

Parameter 0 of method wordpressEntityManagerFactory in com.backend.WordpressConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder' in your configuration.

I have tried downgrading the springframework but than I have a problem with capital letters which I do not understand.

Here is my configuration code:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean wordpressEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("wordpressDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.backend.entities.wordpress").
            properties(new HashMap<String, Object>() {
                {
                    put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy.class.getName());
                    put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", SpringImplicitNamingStrategy.class.getName());
                }
            }).persistenceUnit("wordpress").build();
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager wordpressTransactionManager(@Qualifier("wordpressEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
}
```

}

Comment: "More I have upgraded my springframework to version 2." Not likely. You mean Spring Boot 2 I assume.

Comment: You should give more information about your setup : spring version and its dependencies and their version.

Comment: Yes it is Spring Boot. Here are my Gradle dependecies:  compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-rest', version: '2.0.5.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.0.5.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf', version: '2.0.5.RELEASE'